# TFS 2008 to GIT Migration with multiple apps

Tags: git, tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-migration

I have been asked to migrate a legacy version control TFS2008 to  TFS 2015 using GIT. As newbie to GIT, I need to Understand/create a strategy on how to migrate these source control. My TFS2008 has around 150 (some related and many unrelated) applications.

My current structure is as show below.  Out of 150 apps every quarter there would be release for at least 15-20 apps and I need to create a new branch for that. In TFS 2008 I was able to organize the same under a **DEV** branch and once the project is complete , it gets merged to the prod branch.  This was simple way of doing things with VSS, TFS in Microsoft world.

I learned that better way to use GIT is to different repository for different application but that scenario is ruled out. I tried to understand concept of Orphan branch and sub-modules but they look complex. I need guidance on how these types of structure can be migrated to GIT

**Prod**

-- Applicaiton 1

-- Applicaiton 2

-- Application 3

```
 ..

 ..

 ..
```

-- Applicaiton 149

-- Applicaiton 150

**Dev**

-- Applicaiton 1 Branch - Project Release 1

-- Applicaiton 1 Branch- Project Release 2

-- Some Big Project Affecting multiple Apps

```
 -- Applicaiton 1 Branch for BIG Project

 -- Applicaiton 26 Branch for BIG Project
```

-- Applicaiton 45 Branch - Project Year 2014

Any help in migration strategy to treat each application individually  would be helpful to me.

**If my question has caused confusion. Please do ask for clarifications**

Comment: "I learned that better way to use GIT is to different repository for different application but that scenario is ruled out." Consider ruling it back in. You'll probably have a much better time working with Git if you use it the way it's meant to be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I went with approach of having one repository for each application.

Answer (score 0):

I would first migrate to TFS2017 using TFVC.

Then there are Tools to migrate from TFVC to git, see e.g. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/04/11/import-repositories-from-tfvc-to-git/ or https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/04/11/import-repositories-from-tfvc-to-git/

If you have everything in git, you can split, see e.g. https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/ or https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/

For working with develop and master branches you may have a look for GitFlow.

Comment: Thanks Volker. But I got TFS 2015

Comment: @Matt The principle is the same. Migrate to TFS2015 using TFVC.

Comment: Can you please give me some articles on how to achieve this. Also my remote is tfs 2015 URL not git hub

Comment: @Matt Migrate to TFS 2017 first then to Git is a simple way. If you keep in TFS 2015, you can reference these articles : [Migrating a TFVC team project to a Git team project](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2015/05/19/migrating-a-tfvc-team-project-to-a-git-team-project-along-with-changeset-history-in-tfs/)  and [Converting a TFVC Repository to Git](https://www.concurrency.com/blog/may-2016/converting-tfvc-to-git)

Comment: @Andy -  I am unable to find anything in the article using which my use case is satisfied. Please help my scenario is feasible